# Removing all spaces in L column and add double pipes (VBA Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to remove all spaces in `column L`.

`Column L` contains data like these `with pipes`:

```
data | data | data | data
```

Is there a macro which can make it into this with `double pipes`:

```
data||data||data||data
```

Column L also contains just single data, in that case, nothing should happen:

```
data
```

I hope this is possible, Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do this with Excel's own `Find` and `Replace`.

Comment: Yes, use Control + H to bring up the find and replace dialogue box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's using control + H in a macro. You can also do it without using the macro.

```
Sub FindReplace()

    Cells.Replace What:=" | ", Replacement:="||", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Cells.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Sec gonna try this out!

Comment: Great, it's working now indeed it replaces every | with double ||

Do you also know how I could delete all the spaces in Column L?

Comment: How does your data look? My macro will change space pipe space to just pipe pipe. Are the spaces at the beginning or end? Is there once space at a time, or multiple spaces? The newest edit I posted will also replace all single spaces with nothing.

Comment: Sec I'm going to play with the code, this helped me really good, will report if any issues! <3

Comment: Just a heads up for the future, I created this code by preforming the action while the macro recorder was enabled. You might want to google it - its the easiest way to create simple codes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do that with a worksheet formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN("||",,TRIM(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Cells.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Is this also possible just for column L? Right now it removes every space in the hole sheet.

Thanks very much!

Comment: To do it just for column L, add Columns("L:L").Select to the start and then change cells.replace to selection.replace